# surface area of a spherical balloon is increasing at a rate of 100 cm²/s

Tags: calculus

The surface area of a spherical balloon is increasing at a rate of 100 cm²/s when the balloon has a volume of 100 cm³. Determine the rate at which the volume is increasing at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Both the derivative of the surface area and the derivative of the volume contain the rate of change of the radius of the balloon (d$r$). You can use this to solve for d$r$ from the surface area derivative and plug into the volume derivative to find your rate of change.